# Could not resolve the two-way binding attribute 'visibility' on type 'android.support.constraint.Group'

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-constraintlayout

I have two groups defined inside a ConstraintLayout in my layout. I want them to have visibility opposite to each other. So if group1 is visible then group2 should be gone and vice versa. I am trying to use data binding to achieve this.

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

</data>

<android.support.constraint.Group
                    android:id="@+id/group1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="..." />

<android.support.constraint.Group
                    android:id="@+id/group2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="@{group1.visibility == View.VISIBLE? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                    app:constraint_referenced_ids="..." />
```

But I am getting a compilation error that says:

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not resolve the two-way binding attribute 'visibility' on type 'android.support.constraint.Group'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why that error is happening, but this worked for me:

```
    group1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
```

With that said, I couldn't get the `constraint.Group` to work as advertised.  Also, to make them opposite each other, presumably you would need similar logic in `group1`'s visibility, but that would be circular.  Why not bind these to a ViewModel that controls when each should be visible?

Comment: So I wanted this kind of logic because it makes it easier to change the view behaviour from the preview itself. I can just do `tools:visibility="gone"` and the group2 will become visible on its own.
Anyways getVisibility() works for the first time only, any changes in groep1 are not reflected in group2..

Comment: blame the editor's kotlin auto-complete. what those xmls want is java.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `android:visibility` doesn't support two-way data binding. There is no event to notify when the visibility changes, so there is no way to notify when the property should update.

Comment: I didn't get it. Why I can do `android:visibility="@{viewmodel.empty ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"` but I can't do `android:visibility="@{imageview.visibility}"` ?

Because in my case this is what the compiler is complaining.

Comment: @FilipeBezerradeSousa your `viewmodel.empty` is bindable. View.visibility is not.

Answer (score 0):

## It "works". Kind of:

```
<android.support.constraint.Group
                android:id="@+id/group1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="@{viewmodel.shouldShow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="..." />

<android.support.constraint.Group
                android:id="@+id/group2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="@{group1.visibility == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="..." />
```

This works because the engine doesn't actually bind one View's visibility to another View's visibility. It notices that both bindings ultimately resolve to the same, bindable source: property of the viewModel - and generates another binding to the same source. It's merely a syntactic sugar (possibly that's why it depends on details that shouldn't matter, like the order of views in XML). I think it was meant to cut down on repetition and nothing more.

Actual binding to another View's property is possible where the property has all the piping for two-way databinding. Like `EditText.text` or `CheckBox.checked`. In those cases you get actual View-to-View binding.